# (Ajax) Converting from px to other units for a pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have this code for creating an in-window pop up that depends on a specified width in the HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //

//When you click on a link with class of poplight and the href starts with a # 

$('a.poplight[href^=#]').click(function() {
    var popID = $(this).attr('rel'); //Get Popup Name
    var popURL = $(this).attr('href'); //Get Popup href to define size

    //Pull Query & Variables from href URL
    var query= popURL.split('?');
    var dim= query[1].split('&');
    var popWidth = dim[0].split('=')[1]; //Gets the first query string value

    //Fade in the Popup and add close buttonpx
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': Number( popWidth ) }).prepend('<a href="#" class="close">Close</a>');

    //Define margin for center alignment (vertical   horizontal) - we add 50px to the height/width to accomodate for the padding  and border width defined in the css
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height()) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    //Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    //Fade in Background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>'); //Add the fade layer to bottom of the body tag.
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}).fadeIn(); //Fade in the fade layer - .css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=80)'}) is used to fix the IE Bug on fading transparencies 
    return false;
});

//Close Popups and Fade Layer

$('a.close, #fade').live('click', function() { //When clicking on the close or fade layer...
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
    $('#fade, a.close').remove();  //fade them both out
    });
    return false;
});

});

...

<a href="#?w=900" rel="about" class="poplight">about</a></b> / <a href="#?w=700" rel="writing" class="poplight">writer</a> / <a href="#?w=700" rel="code" class="poplight">coder</a>

...

<div id="about" class="popup_block"></div>
<div id="writing" class="popup_block"></div>
<div id="code" class="popup_block"></div>
```

That automatically and only accepts px units of measurement, not anything else. I want to make the site responsive so I'd like to be able to control it in em/vh/vw/% (depending) but I don't really know any Ajax so I don't know how.

Any help would be great!

I did try typing it in the link but it didn't give the div any width at all.

Comment: @Yogi Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe start [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog)?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a CSS-alternative to achieve what I want - thanks for letting me know how outdated this code is.